# Why isn't twitter tweeting new blog entries?

Tags: support, status-completed, blog

WordPress has a Twitter plugin, but it does not seem to be automatically tweeting new posts.  Is there a way to setup the plugin to automatically tweet new posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch.  It seems like Twitterfeed stopped updating a few of the blog/twitter combos in our account.  I don't really have an explanation for why.  Removing the combo and adding it back appears to have fixed it though.